# How to verify connected device to website?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, web

I want to verify that the device connecting to the site has an android or ios operating system, how should I proceed. How can I interact Android and Ios website?

Comment: Check the user agent (which can easily be faked)

Comment: This is not my need actually. I need reliable verify.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, too bad. If you do not trust the client you cannot know what type of client you are dealing with.

Comment: This is not about my clients, ı just want to prevent file leak

Comment: Not your client, *the* client, the client sending the request to your server. If you want to protect your data authenticate the client / user / request.